# Angularjs: Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm doing some small exercises to learn AngularJS, trying to understand how to work with promises at the moment.

In the following exercise, I'm trying to get some data async. I can see the data in the console.log but the promise is returned NULL.

- GET /entries 200 OK
- Promise is resolved: null

Anyone experienced can give me some advice to understand what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks for looking!

```
angular.module('questions', [])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
            'MyServiceData': function(EntriesService) {
                return EntriesService.promise;
            }
        }
    })
})

.service('EntriesService', function($http) {

    var entries = null;

    var promise = $http.get('entries').success(function (data) {
        entries = data;
    });

    return {
        promise: promise,
        all: function() {
            return entries;
        }
    };
})

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'EntriesService', function($scope, EntriesService) {

  console.log('Promise is resolved: ' + EntriesService.all());

  $scope.title = "Q&A Module";

  $scope.entries = EntriesService.all() || [];

  $scope.addMessage = function() {
    $scope.entries.push({
        author: "myAuthor",
        message: $scope.message
    });
  };

}]);
```

/************** Thanks everyone for your help so far *************/

After taking the advice of @bibs I came up with the following solution, that's clear using ngResource:

```
angular.module('questions', ['ngResource'])

.factory('EntriesService', function($resource){
  return $resource('/entries', {});
})

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'EntriesService', function($scope, EntriesService) {

  $scope.title = "Q&A Module";

  $scope.entries = [];

  EntriesService.query(function(response){
    $scope.entries = response;        
  });

  $scope.addMessage = function() {
    $scope.entries.push({
        author: "myAuthor",
        message: $scope.message
    });
  };

}]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It looks like your promise has yet to be resolved at the time you log `EntriesService.all()`, and hence that value is still null.

Comment: Tanks for looking @bibs! 

I'd like to get some data asynchronously at anytime the mainCtrl is called, so in this case, I want to know how "EntriesService" can have the data available at the time I console.log() it! 

I'm still learning so I thought that, by creating a "service" and using promise this would return me the data. It's obvious here, that I didn't quiet understand promises and for that reason, data is not available in the ctrl when I initialize it.

How should I write it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the data in the callback. Since `entries` maybe empty before the data arrives, the `all()` function is not quite useful in this case.

Try this, you should be able to chain `then()` method to *synchronously* get data.

```
.service('EntriesService', function ($http) {
    var services = {
        all: function () {
            var promise = $http.get('entries').success(function (data) {
                entries = data;
            }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                //error
            });
            return promise;
        },

        someOtherServices: function(){
            var promise = ....
            return promise;
        }

        return services;
    }
});

$scope.entries = [];
EntriesService.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.entries = data;
});
```

Comment: Hi sza, thanks a lot for your help!

I guess, for someone learning this is ok, but is this the correct way of doing this ? *not your solution, but what I've had written

Comment: @heldrida No problem, let me update my answer to show some extensible pattern relating to the http calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data returned by the server to be immediately reflected in your view:

```
.service('EntriesService', function($http) {

    var entries = [];

    var promise = $http.get('entries').success(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            entries[i] = data[i];
        }
    });

    return {
        promise: promise,
        all: entries
    };
})

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'EntriesService', function($scope, EntriesService) {

  $scope.title = "Q&A Module";

  $scope.entries = EntriesService.all;

  $scope.addMessage = function() {
    $scope.entries.push({
        author: "myAuthor",
        message: $scope.message
    });
  };
```

You may want to check out `$resource` to do this for you: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking @bibs! This is working and it really helps me to start understanding how promise works.

I'm going to read about $resource and do a few exercises and try to come out with a working solution.

Thank you!